# Change E-Mail Address Where Notifications Go

Tags: support, email

I would like to change my e-mail address where notifications are sent to. Is this possible, if so how?

I cannot even find my profile where I can edit things..

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Then the question remains on how we can change the notification e-mail address, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of your profile/settings. You can use this link to get there directly: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current

[image]

(or any other site, it will be updated network-wide as the page itself says)

The left menu contains other sections you can change, such as your About Me.